# The transpositions in $S_n$ together generate $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I use this notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

The proof says $(a_1a_2...a_k) = (a_1a_k)...(a_1a_3)(a_1a_2)$. I can see that $a_k$ maps to $a_1$, but not how $a_1$ maps to $a_k$. By definition $a_1$ gets send to $a_2$ which is not the same as $a_k$. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want $a_1$ to be mapped to $a_k$? You explain yourself that the permutation on the LHS maps $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$ for $i<k$. The RHS is the product in $S_n$ of the permutations, i.e. the composition of the permutations. So $a_1$ is mapped to $a_2$, exactly as you noted.

For the other ones, any $a_i$ with $1<i<k$ gets mapped first to $a_1$ by the term $(a_1 a_i)$ and then to $a_{i+1}$ by the term $(a_1 a_{i+1})$.

Comment: Unless I'm reading the definition wrong $(a_1a_k)$ means $a_1$ gets mapped to $a_k$.

Comment: I guess my question boils down to: doesn't $(a_1a_k)...(a_1a_3)(a_1a_2)$ mean that $a_1$ gets send to all $a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ in which case it's not a function anymore.

Comment: @PeldePinda No, the RHS is the composition of the permutations.

Comment: So $a_1$ gets sent to $a_2$ by the first term $(a_1a_2)$ (composition is from right to left). All the other permutation leave $a_2$ fixed, so $a_1$ is sent to $a_2$ by the composition. Now $a_2$ is sent to $a_1$ by the first term $(a_1a_2)$, and then to $a_3$ by the following term $(a_1a_3)$. $a_3$ is not changed by the first term, but is sent to $a_1$ by the following term, and then to $a_4$ by the next term $(a_1a_4)$, etc.

Comment: So that is different from (1 5 2)(3 4)? And if yes, how can I tell the difference?

Comment: It's not different : in both case we are composing bijections $\{1,\cdots, n\}\to \{1,\cdots, n\}$.